# Cannot connect to docker compose network from host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two docker images. one is a postgresql database and the other is a FastAPI. I tried running both using `docker run` and it all works correctly. I can use `127.0.0.1:8000/docs` and access the Swagger UI. The problem starts when using docker compose.
Here my file:

```yaml
services:
 
  db:
    image: postgres
    # restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: my-user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  api:
    image: api_rest
    # restart: always
    # links:
    #   - db
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

The outputs seems Ok, as if both services are connecting. However, accessing `127.0.0.1:8000/docs` gives nothing. I understood that using `ports` command should already expose the container IP with the host.
Doing some debugging I did `docker container inspect <MY FASTAPI CONTAINER ID>` and got:

```
"Networks": {
                "network_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "api",
                        "b9201abec1c2"
                    ],
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:03",
                    "NetworkID": "fbde8b8a0dc3ff02b24b9c59290dd7bb98256774c1e8e848beb577b77b7d7152",
                    "EndpointID": "00decc867548762ee60fa0db31c727fac80adf2fc5636060565ebaf5d64165b5",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.21.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "DNSNames": [
                        "fast-api-1",
                        "api",
                        "b9201abec1c2"
                    ]
```

I therefore try both `172.21.0.1` and `172.21.0.3` but no luck.

BTW: the output of docker compose is:

```bash
Attaching to fast-api-1, postgres-db-1
postgres-db-1   | 
postgres-db-1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres-db-1   | 
postgres-db-1   | 2024-03-27 15:47:30.892 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres-db-1   | 2024-03-27 15:47:30.892 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres-db-1   | 2024-03-27 15:47:30.892 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres-db-1   | 2024-03-27 15:47:30.907 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-db-1   | 2024-03-27 15:47:30.947 UTC [29] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-03-27 15:37:55 UTC
postgres-db-1   | 2024-03-27 15:47:30.973 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/']
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Loading environment from 'api_rest/docker.env'
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Started reloader process [7] using WatchFiles
fast-api-1  | Connecting to database using postgresql+psycopg2://my-user:password@db:5432/postgres
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Started server process [9]
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

The output of `docker ps`

```
4eca35c35e45   api_rest      "/bin/sh -c 'uvicorn…"   About a minute ago   Up 3 seconds       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   fast-api-1
280b95fd9257   postgres-db   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago          Up 3 seconds       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   postgres-db-1
```

I tried changing port to `127.0.0.1:8000:8000` because is the IP I use on my web browser but no luck. Also, the command of `extra_hosts` I do not understand but it changes nothing.

Relevant information is:

- I am running all un an Ubuntu Oracle VM (running on windows)
- The VM does not have internet connection because of some proxy issues, etc. But as this seems all internal I thought it is nor relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is visible here:

```
fast-api-1  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Uvicorn is running with the socket bound to the default host `127.0.0.1`, which is the localhost of the *container*, meaning that it will only accept traffic from within the container itself.

See for example [this page](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/#build-a-docker-image-with-a-single-file-fastapi) for a complete example, but in short you need to do something along the lines of the following:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", ...]
```

Using `0.0.0.0` as the host will accept traffic from outside of the container too.

You should also just remove the `extra_hosts`, it's not needed. Then you should be able to connect from the host machine using `127.0.0.1:8000` just like that.